# How Send SSL Certificate With Java HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection

I want to send something.crt with HttpURLConnection.

It always says something like:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
>
> String requestURL = "https://some.thing.com:5874/SomeService/OperationsEndpoint1";
>
> HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new
>
> URL(requestURL).openConnection();
>
> connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
>
> String httpCode = connection.getResponseCode();
>
> String responseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

Answer (score 4):

You would use the `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` class, not `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

- Check out [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/436057/java-io/java/SSL-HttpURLConnection#1938498)

Comment: Thanks but not working, same error.

Comment: Can you give some more details. Maybe some code could help